# C# How do I use a variable in multiple classes?

Tags: c#

I have decided to attempt to make a text based game, at this point in time I am attempting to find a way to keep the characters stats on screen after using Console.Clear.

The way I have attempted to do it is by creating a function:

```
    static void Stats()
```

The problem I am running into is that I have to use a variable that is located in the main section of the code:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
```

I can't however work out how to do this, one way I have found when looking it up is to create a string outside of the functions:

```
     public static string Player_Gender;
```

As far as I can tell though this is frowned upon. If I am wrong in believing this please let me know and I can continue to do it this way, however if this is correct please can you give me an alternative to this?

I haven't completed the function yet as I want to solve this problem before changing my code quite a bit but this is what it will roughly look like with the addition of other stats etc.

```
    static void Stats()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("| |================================| |");
        Console.WriteLine("| | Character description + stats: | |");
        Console.WriteLine("| | Gender: {0}                    | |", Player_Gender);
    }
```

The variables currently however are stored here:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Ints:
        int correct = 0;
        int Player_One_Handed = 0;
        int Player_Two_Handed = 0;
        int Player_Ranged_Weapon = 0;
        int Player_Magic = 0;
        int Arraycount = 0;
        int Player_Attack_Type = 0;
        int Player_One_Weapon_Damage = 2;
        int Player_Two_Weapon_Damage = 2;
        int Player_Ranged_Weapon_Damage = 2;
        int Player_Magic_Damage = 2;
        int Player_Health_Points = 20;
        int Player_Mana_Points = 12;
        int Enemy_Health_Points;
        int Enemy_Maximum_Damage;
        int Player_Inventory_Money = 0;
        int Player_Inventory_Experience = 0;
        int Player_Quest_Progress = 0;
        int Player_Quest_Goal;
        int Player_EXP = 0;
        int Player_Checked_For_Item = 0;
        int Player_Quest_Objective_Complete = 0;

        //Strings:
        string Player_Gender_Confirm;
        string Player_Race;
        string Player_Race_Confirm;
        string Player_Class;
        string Player_Class_Confirm;
        string[] Inventory = new string[20];
        string Enemy_Name;
        string Player_Quest = " ";
        string Quest_Accepted;
        string Player_Quest_Enemy;
```

Comment: Do you know how to write a `class`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, could you please show me how I can use a class to fix this problem?

Comment: @MethodMan I am currently doing C# at College in computer science, I assume that we will learn about this however we haven't quite touched upon it

Comment: @Kian - Please go read some tutorial sites for C# and OOP - then come back and ask any questions you have. It's off-topic here to get programming tutorials. This question should be closed.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't want anyone to explain to me how to use classes, I was just hoping the person could show me an example of how to use a class to help my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing is to pass the value in as a parameter:

```
static void Stats(string gender)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("| |================================| |");
    Console.WriteLine("| | Character description + stats: | |");
    Console.WriteLine("| | Gender: {0}                    | |", gender);
}
```

Use like so:

```
Stats(Player_Gender);
```

But that's not such a good idea after all, because you don't want to pass in 25 different parameters.

Instead, write a new class that has all your player variables in it. Include every variable that describes a player, and include no variables that don't describe a player.

```
public class Player
{
    public int OneHanded { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Race { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }

    //  ...etc. etc. -- include EVERYTHING that is a property of a player. 

    //  Now your Stats() method has direct access to all the player's properties
    //  Print stats for THIS player
    public void PrintStats()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("| |================================| |");
        Console.WriteLine("| | Character description + stats: | |");
        Console.WriteLine("| | Gender: {0}                    | |", Gender);
        Console.WriteLine("| | Race: {0}                    | |", Race);
    }
}
```

You're going to have trouble with alignment in those `Console.WriteLine()` calls. `Console.WriteLine()` works the same way as `String.Format()`, though, so you have [some options to control alignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

And in Main...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var player = new Player();

    //  Whatever
    player.Name = "Bob";
    player.Gender = "Male";

    //  print stats for Bob
    player.PrintStats();

    var otherPlayer = new Player();
    otherPlayer.Name = "Fred";

    //  print stats for Fred
    otherPlayer.PrintStats();
```

There we begin to see the value of writing a class: With almost zero additional effort and almost zero additional code clutter, you can have two players with identical sets of properties, instead of one. You can reinitialize a player in one line:

```
player = new Player();
```

You can pass everything there is to know about a given player to another method very simply:

```
player.Assault(otherPlayer);
```

And so on.